# Node: Hit endpoint that returns a CSV file and send the contents to client

Tags: node.js, csv, express

I'm given an endpoint that returns a CSV file. I want to hit that end point, read the data, and send it to the client. This is what I have right now.

```
app.get('/data', (req, res) => {
  request('foo.com/downloadCSV', (error, response, body) => {
    res.send(csvToJson(body));
  });
});
```

So on the front end, I hit '/data', which then uses the request library to make the call to get the CSV data. The body for the CSV is in 'body'. The 'csvToJson' function just formats the data given into arrays/json.

When I console.log the response on my client, my body is: ReadableStream, locked(...)

How do I get the data to the client?

**Edit:**

Here is my csvToJson function:

```
const csvToJson = (csv) => {
  const content = csv.split('\r');
  const header = content[0].split(',');
  return _.tail(content).map((row) => {
    return _.zipObject(header, row.split(','));
  });
}
```

Comment: check the body on server side before sending it to the client, also errores/response may have helpful information

Comment: body is showing me exactly what i want

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your code and it works. In public folder I've created sample.csv.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var request = require('request');
var _ = require('lodash');

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/data', (req, res) => {
  request('http://localhost:3000/sample.csv', (error, response, body) => {
    res.send(csvToJson(body));
  });
});

const csvToJson = (csv) => {
  const content = csv.split('\n');
  const header = content[0].split(',');
  return _.tail(content).map((row) => {
    return _.zipObject(header, row.split(','));
  });
}

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Listening on port 3000!')
})
```

Sample.csv file:

```
a,b,c,d
1,2,3,4
2,1,5,6
54,3,1,12
1,2,3,4
```

Result:

[image]

Problem maybe is with your csv file which your are downloading from other service.

Comment: Getting the error: jsonStream.on is not a function. I posted my csvToJson function in the edit

Comment: Which library do you use for csv to json transformation?

Comment: I didn't use any. I found a function that used lodash that did it. That function is in the original post.

Comment: I ran your code and I still get ReadableStream. I get the CSV from a third party. I was able to read the stream on the front end

Answer (score 0):

My React front end:

```
componentDidMount() {
  fetch('/data').then(response => {
    var decoder = new TextDecoder();
    var reader = response.body.getReader();

    // read() returns a promise that resolves
    // when a value has been received
    reader.read().then(function processResult(result) {
      if (result.done) return;
      console.log(
        decoder.decode(result.value, {stream: true})
      );

      // Read some more, and recall this function
      return reader.read().then(processResult);
    });
  });
}
```

This will end the ReadableStream and get the data out of it.